# Parse string with specific format

Tags: objective-c, format

I have a quick question regarding parsing string using objective C. Currently, I have a format that outputs *A_1_2_3_4_~. This string has a start of message (*), header (A), value (1), and end of message (~). I've written this code for an arduino, but can't seem to get it to work correctly in objective c. What the function does is that it separates each value and categories it. Very efficient and sturdy. If I send *A_1_1_1_~, it recognizes that A is for something, with value 1, 1, 1. Anyways, here the code:

```
//protocol for parsing
-(void)protocol:(NSString*)input type:(Boolean*)comType
{
    Byte place = 0, index, ID, average, setGet; //any value < 256
    int probeType, tempType;
    char Header;
    NSString *output; //used for parsing
    double probeValue, tempValue;

//    if(comType){}
//    //wire = ""; //reset wire
//    else
//        analog.text = @"";//serial = ""; //reset serial

    //if error in message example: A_1_1_A_1_A_A_A*A_1_1_8.27_1_15.67_3_~
    //use '*' as start of message character and grab from *A_1_1_8.27_1_15.67_3_~

    probeType = input.length; //get length of string

    index = [input rangeOfString:@"*" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location; //index = input.lastIndexOf("*"); //index contains start of message
    if(index < 0)  //not available or incorrect format
        return;
    input = [input substringFromIndex:index]; //remove incorrect stuff
    average = [input rangeOfString:@"~"].location; //input.indexOf("~", index); //grab end of message
    input = [input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index+1, average+index)]; //input = input.substring(index + 1, average + 1); //grab valid string only, lower bandwidth
    //    [self alert: input];
    for(Byte i = 0; i < 8; i++) //limit the message length as well
    {
        //        index = [input rangeOfString:@"_"].location; //grab location of
        index = [input rangeOfString:@"_" options:Nil range:NSMakeRange(place, input.length)].location;//index = input.indexOf("_", place); //gets first update
        //        [self alert:index];
        if(index < 0 || [input characterAtIndex:index+1] == '~')//input.substring(place, index + 1) == "~") //no '_' found or EOM
            break; //two birds one stone
        output = [input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(place, index)];//output = input.substring(place, index); //grab in between
        //input = [input stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, index) withString:@""];//remove already read

        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: //header
                Header = [output characterAtIndex:0]; //fast conversion from String to char
                break;
            case 1: //ID
                ID = [output intValue]; //toInt() returns long...not int; perfect for conductivity
                break;
            case 2: //Probe Type
                probeType = [output intValue];
                break;
            case 3: //Probe Value
                probeValue = [output doubleValue];
                break;
            case 4: //Temperature Type
                tempType = [output intValue];
                break;
            case 5: //Temperature Value
                tempValue = [output doubleValue];
                break;
            case 6: //Average
                average = [output intValue];
                break;
            case 7:
                setGet = [output intValue];
                break;
        }
        place = index + 1;
        [self alert: output];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is "efficient and sturdy," but it doesn't work. Which is it?

Comment: The `rangeOfString:` method returns an `NSRange` struct. The `location` field has a type of `NSUInteger`. Therefore, you need to change your `index` variable to have a type of `NSUInteger`. Since it is unsigned, you can't check `if (index < 0)`. You need `if (index == NSNotFound)`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get out, just the string of numbers between *A and ~ ? Is the header always *A, or can it be something else?

Comment: @trudyscousin: It's efficient and sturdy for the arduino. I'm not very familiar with objective C, so I can't make it work...for now.

Comment: @rdelmar: The header can be anything...A->Z. The length can change as well. For example: *A_1_1_~ or *B_1_1_1_1_~ or *C_1_~. This is why we need the end of message char. A does something, B is for something else, and the same for C.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what all your parameters are for what the format can look like, but I would do it like this to extract the numbers from your string. Like your question, I look for the first "*" in the string, searching backwards from the end.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumbers = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
    NSString *s = @"A_1_1_A_1_A_A_A*A_1_1_8.27_1_15.67_3_~"; // test string
    NSInteger locationOfAsterisk = [s rangeOfString:@"*" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;
    if (locationOfAsterisk != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *validString = [s substringFromIndex:locationOfAsterisk + 1];
        NSMutableArray *parsedArray = [[s componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"] mutableCopy];
        NSIndexSet *indxs = [parsedArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [obj rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumbers].location != NSNotFound ;
        }];
        [parsedArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indxs];
        [parsedArray insertObject:[validString substringToIndex:1] atIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",parsedArray);

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Not a valid format");
    }
}
```

This returns an array with the first element being the letter following the asterisk, followed by all the numbers up to the tilde.

Comment: This code works great, but the issue is error checking. You used [[s substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"*"]. What if the string was A_1_1_A_1_A_A_A*A_1_1_8.27_1_15.67_3_~. Or even worse: *A_*A_1_~. It does contain valid information, however index doesn't contain (*), so it's discarded. This is why in the original code, I scanned from the end character (~) to the first instance of (*) to grab the valid length. The rest is discarded. Your code is still excellent nonetheless.

Comment: @NothinRandom, that's why I asked about the format, I didn't know what the parameters were.

Comment: @NothinRandom, I updated my code to what I think should work for you (if you're still interested).

Comment: I also gave it another shot updating what I had earlier, and it works as well. However, I'm still interested in seeing your code!

Answer (score 0):

```
//protocol for parsing
-(void)protocol:(NSString*)inputString type:(Boolean*)comType
{
    int probeType, tempType, index, ID, average, setGet;
    NSMutableString *Header;
//    NSString *output; //used for parsing
    double probeValue, tempValue;

    //if error in message example: A_1_1_A_1_A_A_A*A_1_1_8.27_1_15.67_3_~
    //use '*' as start of message character and grab from *A_1_1_8.27_1_15.67_3_~

    probeType = inputString.length; //steal probeType for now, probeType contains length of string

    index = [inputString rangeOfString:@"*" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location; //index contains SoM, index
    if(index < 0)  //not available
        return;
    inputString = [inputString substringFromIndex:index]; //remove incorrect stuff before SoM
    average = [inputString rangeOfString:@"~"].location; //grab end of message
    inputString = [inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index+1, average)]; //grab valid string from SoM with length
    inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@""]; //need to remove *
    inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"~" withString:@""]; //need to remove ~
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfNumbers = [[inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"] mutableCopy]; //

    int objects = [arrayOfNumbers count]; //no need for ~ sign

    for(int i = 0; i < objects; i++) //limit the message length as well
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: //header
                Header = [arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i]; //[output characterAtIndex:0]; //fast conversion from String to char
                break;
            case 1: //ID
                ID = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue]; //[output intValue]; //toInt() returns long...not int; perfect for conductivity
                break;
            case 2: //Probe Type
                probeType = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                break;
            case 3: //Probe Value
                probeValue = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
                break;
            case 4: //Temperature Type
                tempType = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                break;
            case 5: //Temperature Value
                tempValue = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
                break;
            case 6: //Average
                average = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                break;
            case 7:
                setGet = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                break;
        }
        [self alert: [arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```